# Conditional rendering in React Native with global variable

Tags: javascript, react-native

I know this is horrible convention, but I'm trying to quickly conditionally render screens in my React Native app with global variables (so no redux):

App.js:

```
if (global.clickStatus !== 'clicked') {
      return <Screen1 />;
}

return <Screen2 />;
```

The app begins on Screen1, where there is a button that makes `global.clickStatus = 'clicked'`. When this is clicked, I want Screen2 to render. The problem is, the global.clickStatus doesn't seem to update on my App.js (even though global.clickStatus is changed, it still renders Screen1.

How can I get it to update?

Comment: Do you have a function or class component?

Comment: Better use something like context as this value change wont cause a rerender

Comment: function component

Answer (score 0):

I believe in `<App />` component because it is a function component you can introduce a state if your button is clicked. Then with `clicked` state you can manipulate which component to show.

Similarly like the following - obviously this is a simplified example:

```
const App = () => {
   const [clicked, setClicked] = useState(false);

   return <>
      <div onClick={() => setClicked(true)}>Click me</div>

      { clicked ? <Screen2 /> : <Screen1 /> }
   </>
}
```

Suggested read is [Using the State Hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html).

Answer (score 0):

```
The app begins on Screen1, where there is a button that makes global.clickStatus = 'clicked'
```

When you click the button, you did not set any state for App.js component => no re-render action is made.
I just assume the button is in Screen 1. Try code below:

```js
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  // Create a state
  const [renderIndex, setRenderIndex] = useState(new Date().getTime())
  if (global.clickStatus !== 'clicked') {
    // Assume you have a button in Screen1
    // Pass a callback function from this component to Screen1
    // When button in Screen1 is clicked, call this callback function to update renderIndex => App component will re-render
    return <Screen1 callBack={() => setRenderIndex(new Date().getTime())}/>;
}

return <Screen2 />;
}
```